# Best Framework for HTML5,Css3 and Javascript based Game Application

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am web developer knows HTML5/CSS 3 and Javascript/Jquery. I am new to game development, I want to create Game APP which should run in IOS/Android/Blackberry phones. Which framework i have to choose for mobile based game development using above technologies i know.

In my mind, few options i might get opt are:-

1. Phonegap
2. Appecelator
3. Appmobi
4. Syncha
5. Titanium
   or anything else which i am not aware of.

Do i need to change my javascript code to make it compatible with these framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already done this and can tell what I did, but I think you are a bit confused. If you want to create a game with html5, css3, and javacript, then deploy it to mobile devices as a native app. There are some bigger considerations to make:

1) You are going to need to decide on a javascript-based game engine. There are many to choose from. For my first project, I chose crafty.js It is very light weight and allows the use of other js libraries with it. What you choose is up to you.

2) I then set a h5bp. I also used backbone, require, and jquery in my project, along with crafty.js

3)Develop your game

4)once it works in your browser, you then deploy to phonegap for testing as a native app on your various devices. Trust me, you'll need to do this as each device and the OS build on each device you target may not always perform like its html5 counterpart.

5)Finally as you are able to build each native app package, use your dev license (assuming you have bought one for each device) to publish your app on the various markets: i.e. iTunes, Play, Amazon app store, etc.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have sample Game available with full source code which is running fine locally on chrome browser. Code is using <canvas> tag. Now If i have to deploy to phonegap for testing. What do i need to do to test as a native app? Do I need to change the Js source file?

Comment: nope..just goto phonegap...see how it runs on your device(s)...very easy

Comment: I have created and ran with Phonegap and it worked nicely via Samsung S3  (via direct install using phonegap based APK build).But some of the articles denotes canvas based game rendering with phonegap is bit slow compare to app.mobi or some other framework. Is it true?